# How to update one col pr. row with jquery

Tags: jquery

How can i update only one col pr. row with jquery. 
As you can see on this picture, i only want to update the col to the right, and not the three other cols. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post your html, if you have a table, you could use `$('tr td:last')` or `$('tr').find('td:last')`

Comment: Good idea, Calum. But how can i then update all the rows with only one request and not 6 different request every 5 second. If you understand?
And it's set up in a table

Comment: You can iterate through them with each() so, $('tr td:last').each(function(){ //Get data });

Comment: Thanks Calum, there was the function i needed!

Answer (score 0):

Without the HTML to get a better picture of what you are wanting the first thing I would suggest is that you assign a unique class to the target column like `<td class="processColumn">42</td>` Then you can get an array of just the columns with that class like:

```
var allCellsInColumn = $(".processColumn")
```

Then you can iterate through that array and update each item.